# Quasiquotes in Intellij 14?

Tags: intellij-idea

After installing the newly released IJ14 Community Edition  - the quasiquotes (which had been working on IJ13) popped up on the radar.

[image]

Is there an IJ setting to enable this?

BTW this is a maven build (and works in 13.1 just fine!).  Here is the section of the build related to the quasiquotes.  I have not seen any mention of the plugin not working properly in 14, but input here would be appreciated.

```
        <!-- The following plugin is required to use quasiquotes in Scala 2.10 and is used
             by Spark SQL for code generation. -->
        <compilerPlugins>
          <compilerPlugin>
              <groupId>org.scalamacros</groupId>
              <artifactId>paradise_${scala.version}</artifactId>
              <version>${scala.macros.version}</version>
          </compilerPlugin>
        </compilerPlugins>
```

**UPDATE** I just installed the 14.0.1 update from 11/11/14. This time I tried Intellij Ultimate : but Quasiquotes are still not working.

[image]

**UPDATE**  I have opened a JIRA with JetBrains.   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-133993

Comment: Why not to report it in JetBrains tracking system instead?

Comment: Apparently the community does not feel this were an appropriate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem involves the paradise plugin that provides support for quasiquotes with scala 2.10. It is not working in IJ14 presently.

**UPDATE**  The following is new info on the building with Spark page

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark#ContributingtoSpark-IntelliJ

"Rebuild Project" can fail the first time the project is compiled, because generate source files are not automatically generated. Try clicking the "Generate Sources and Update Folders For All Projects" button in the "Maven Projects" tool window to manually generate these sources.
Compilation may fail with an error like "scalac: bad option: -P:/home/jakub/.m2/repository/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.10.4/2.0.1/paradise_2.10.4-2.0.1.jar". If so, go to Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Scala Compiler and clear the "Additional compiler options" field.  It will work then although the option will come back when the project reimports.  If you try to build any of the projects using quasiquotes (eg., sql) then you will need to make that jar a compiler plugin (just below "Additional compiler options").  Otherwise you will see errors like:

/Users/irashid/github/spark/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/CodeGenerator.scala
Error:(147, 9) value q is not a member of StringContext
 Note: implicit class Evaluate2 is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
        q"""
        ^

Comment: The new link is https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Useful+Developer+Tools#UsefulDeveloperTools-IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a workaround to get it running:
You have to go to the IntelliJ settings, to the "Scala Compiler" and add a plugin: "/home/YOURUSERNAME/.m2/repository/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.10.4/paradise_2.10.4-2.0.1.jar"

Comment: I am building with maven so that setting is not used. I have updated the OP.

Answer (score -2):

It's `s` not `q`:

```
  val x = 5.0
  println(s"$x.toInt")
```

I loaded spark up in Intellij 13 and the macro paradise backport of quaisquotes still shows an error, I don't see how intellij would be able to support this syntax as it's a compiler plugin:
[image]

Comment: Umm (a) I mentioned this was working in IJ13.  (b) q is for quasiquotes (c) this is not my code - it is spark code that compiles on the command line via maven

Comment: Umm (a) spark is scala 2.10 so they use a quasi quote compiler plugin that aliases `q` to quasi quotes since 2.10 doesn't have quasi quotes. (b) Intellij doesn't know about the plugin or how to add it to its grammar.

Comment: How about (a) this is working in IJ13. Note I did not downvote you, to allow a constructive answer.

Comment: (a) is working on every machine on IJ13 in our team  - including my own until doing this upgrade earlier today.  It is interesting that you have it failing here. I double checked and the last change to the source was M Armbrust on 8/23/14 so this is not a source change issue.